# How can I "feed" variables through links to Electron / JavaScript to launch exe's?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to create a launcher for other programs.

That means I want to have a bunch of links, each setting three different variables that, when joined, would create the path of an executable. Let's say Pre-Path, Main-Path and Launch-Commands. And the executable would run.

I've looked around about "how you run exe's through JavaScript / Electron" but the examples I saw are of "singular" solutions. As in, the code you'd put in a singular, specific link, to launch a specific application.

How could I go creating a) code that sets three variables for each link and, if clicked, calls a function that joins them in a path and "runs it" and b) this function?

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery in your app?  It would not be very difficult to setup a click listener that would forward multiple parameters to the back end with ipcRenderer listeners.

Comment: Nope, since the only stuff I know is HTML and CSS. I'm trying to learn the basics of JS and Electron through this project (I'm a "read-copy-tweak-mutate-write-from-scratch-fail-and-try-again" learner). That does mean, though, that if jQuery would have something useful to offer / would be easy and useful to include in it, no problem, I'd simply start learning the basics of jQuery as well :-)

Comment: If that helps, [this](https://github.com/Derducken/Shadow_Launcher) is the project I'm trying to make. I made (and know how to make) "the front end as a (static) site". Now I'm trying to learn how to make it work as a proper Windows (or whatever platform) program. Preferably, as lightweight as possible.